# generate x digit random number in sql server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008, random

I have to generate 12 digit number(bigint) in sql server 2008 R2 itsleft. i have used these methods which i found on the internet

```
convert(numeric(12,0),rand() * 999999999999)
```

and

```
RIGHT(CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS VARBINARY(36)) AS BIGINT), 12)
```

while these do work the problem is sometimes the generated number has leading zeroes and that is stripped resulting in a 10 or 11 digit number.

Is there a consistent way to generate x digit numbers in sql?

Thanks. this is very urgent.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

One solution is to just make sure it's in the 12 digit range.

```
convert(numeric(12,0),rand() * 899999999999) + 100000000000
```

Answer (score 5):

How about add a random number to 100000000000

Answer (score 3):

Simple one line random number generation in SQL Server

```
Select LEFT(SUBSTRING (RTRIM(RAND()) + SUBSTRING(RTRIM(RAND()),3,11), 3,11),6) as RandomNumber
```

Above query will give you 6 digit random number. If you want more or less digit number then simply change the length mention at the end of the line. Ex. (6 to 4 or 8 likewise Maximum limit is 11)

Answer (score 0):

Simply showcasing generate a number in the SQL server.

Run this query in SQL server get to return the generate 9 digits random number.

```
select ABS(CHECKSUM(NewId()))
```

Many examples are available on the browser but this solution is very easy to use as a unique number.