# Select random rows and stop when a specific sum/total is reached

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

It was asked by compcobalt (for SQL Server **2012**) via this thread : [Select random rows and stop when a specific sum/total is reached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15278143/select-random-rows-and-stop-when-a-specific-sum-total-is-reached)

**Detail:**

---

I'm using SQL Server 2012 and I'm trying to do something like this:

```
SELECT SUM(MILES) from tblName WHERE 
mDate > = '03/01/2012' and 
mDate <= '03/31/2012' 
-- and...
/* 
   now I want to add here do until the SUM of Miles 
   is equal to or greater then '3250' and get the 
   results rows randomly
*/
```

So in other words, I want to select random rows from a table that have a specified from and to date and stop when the sum of miles is at or over the number: 3250

---

But my question is how to do it with SQL Server **2000** ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky question and can be done. My Idea is
1.give row number to your table.
2.then generate random numbers.
3.Select rows with the help of row_number and randomly generated number.
4. keep doing it till the sum is as you with.

But the issue is SQL server 2000 doesn't have row_number function 
take help from http://forums.asp.net/t/1630106.aspx/1

for generating random number plz see

"[generate x digit random number in sql server 2008 R2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7709042/generate-x-digit-random-number-in-sql-server-2008-r2)"

Good luck

Please update me if i am of any help

Regards

Ashutosh Arya